# How to remove ng-repeat table row without allowing the table to be empty?

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to delete rows in a table but I do not want it to be completely empty ever... the table starts with one row, but the user can add new rows but also delete all rows, rendering the table empty. This is my code for adding and deleting rows in my controller:

```
$scope.rowItems = [{}];

$scope.addRowItems = function() {
    $scope.rowItems.push(rowItem); 
}

$scope.deleteRowItem = function(item) {
    $scope.rowItems.splice(item, 1);
}
```

And this is my code for my HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat:"rowItem in rowItems track by $index">
   ...rest of row here...
</tr>
```

Any and all help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check the length of the array before splicing it, and optionally can show an alert to the user warning him that at least one row should be present in the table.

```
$scope.deleteRowItem = function(item) {
  if($scope.rowItems.length > 1) {
    $scope.rowItems.splice(item, 1);
  } else {
    alert("Can't remove the only row");
  }
}
```

Comment: This would work only when item `index` has been passed `.splice` function, not item..

Comment: @PankajParkar -- thanks for pointing it out. As OP has not clarified what `item` will represent, I've assumed that it will be the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can add static row in HTML view like that:

```
<tr>
   ...static row columns are here...
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat:"rowItem in rowItems track by $index">
   ...rest of row here...
</tr>
```

It's good idea because you can add action buttons/input in first `tr` and simply add action events to add new row or something else

Or you can restrict deletion of rows in component logic as it was shown by [@31piy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2019247/31piy)